# MPAndroidChart PieChart is not displayed when used inside ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, mpandroidchart

I want to show a `PieChart` in my fragment.
Following is the xml I have written,

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/graphContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart
                android:id="@+id/piechart"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
```

The problem is, `PieChart` is not working if I give `match_parent` or `wrap_content`. If i give fixed height and width it works fine. Also, if I remove the `ScrollView` , it works like a charm! So what needs to be done in case of `ScrollView`?

Comment: Add a fixed height for the piechart

Comment: @PhilippJahoda: Have you read the whole question?

Comment: Yes, and that is my suggestion.

Comment: I suppose it is a custom class you haven't written yourself; when you write a custom class you have to deal with all the different constructors that "initialize" an object. It MIGHT be that match_parent doesn't trigger any. Can you put a print in the constructor and check if it gets executed when being placed in the view?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda kindly specify the height?

Answer (score -2):

Add below attribute in scroll view

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

[Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617727/linearlayout-achartengine-chart-not-displaying-in-scrollview)